# MySQL Function Error 1442

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION TWO_FRONT(txt CHAR(30))
RETURNS CHAR(2)
RETURN SUBSTRING(txt, 1, 2);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CHECK_AVABILITY(t_nama CHAR(30))
RETURNS INT(4)
BEGIN
DECLARE vreturn INT(4);
DECLARE P CHAR(8);
SET p = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tabel_user WHERE nama like CONCAT(TWO_FRONT(t_nama),'%'));
IF ISNULL(p)THEN
    SET vreturn = 0;
ELSE
    SET vreturn = SUBSTRING(p, 4, 4);
END IF;
RETURN vreturn;
END $$
DELIMITER;

CREATE FUNCTION COMBINE(fn CHAR(2), nu CHAR(4))
RETURNS CHAR(7)
RETURN CONCAT(UPPER(fn),'-',nu);

CREATE TRIGGER cast_id AFTER INSERT ON tabel_user 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE tabel_user SET id = COMBINE(TWO_FRONT(OLD.nama),CHECK_AVABILITY(OLD.nama)) WHERE id = OLD.id;
END;
```

Everyting is okay but after i insert this...

```
INSERT INTO tabel_user VALUES('','Blabla');
```

error is coming...

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'tabel_user' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Can you help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending MySQL mixed messages.

cast_id fires after `INSERT`, but it is looking for `OLD.nama` and `OLD.id`. `OLD`, on the other hand, only exists when there is an `UPDATE` being called.  I think you meant:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cast_id AFTER INSERT ON tabel_user 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    -- notice no "UPDATE" or "WHERE", "SET" implies "set on this current row"
    SET NEW.id = COMBINE(TWO_FRONT(NEW.nama),CHECK_AVABILITY(NEW.nama));
END;
```

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER cast_id BEFORE INSERT ON tabel_user 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.id = COMBINE(TWO_FRONT(NEW.nama),CHECK_AVABILITY(NEW.nama));
END;

Thanks but some change ind AFTER to BEFORE